# sending kik message with timer without calling the page

Tags: php, timer, kik

I'm programming a calendar website. The reminder message should be sent using kik.
Therefore I need to send a message even if the page is not actually called.
Is there a possibility to do this, for example using a timer that is set when the date/event is 
put into the calendar from the user

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. The Kik API is structured in a way that messages can only be sent with the user's explicit permission.

Push notifications are an alternative for your kind of use-case. Check out the documentation here: http://dev.kik.com/docs/#push